# Categories are not appearing when click on Manage Categories showing Error Source model in the Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin, category, eav

I'm into big trouble today and for the last 24 hours I'm trying to fix it up with one of my production site. I had uploaded a theme but theme didn't work as expected so I deleted the theme and all its attributes. But now I'm into a bigger issue.

When I click on Manage Categories in Admin Panel, it displays below error. Website is perfectly working.

```
There has been an error processing your request

Source model "porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode" not found for attribute "sw_product_staticblock_tab_1"
```

I have already tried to search such file in the DB but I didn't find any file with such name.

Could you please help me resolve this issue?

Where and how to find this file or is there any easy fix that can remove this error.

Please help me...

fyi... I'm using RWD theme.

Waiting for your reply guys..

Thanks
Amit

Comment: is this attribute exists in backend : `sw_product_staticblock_tab_1` , also is `Manage Products section` working fine ?

Comment: if it exists, than you need to `unassign` [dont delete ] that attribute from attribute set or else take database backup and than remove attribute from `eav_attribute` table....

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact that your theme added source models to some attributes.

First, backup your database.

Then you should try to run the following:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model = 'porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode';
```

After that you should try to reindex.

Answer (score 0):

if the attribute exists in backend : **sw_product_staticblock_tab_1** than unassign the attribute from attribute set. if not exists , than take database backup & than delete the attribute **sw_product_staticblock_tab_1**  from the `eav_attribute` table.